# Sencha Touch - Pubnub integration

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, pubnub

Has anyone managed to integrate a Pubnub service into Sencha Touch yet?

I was thinking about just including the library that constantly makes the requests but not quite sure how it will react to everything else. Wondering if anyone has actually got a proper solution yet and if this will work with Native, which I guess makes requests and will work as normal anyway?

Thanks, Dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this certainly is possible.  To test it out, I made a chat example.

Live demo [here](http://pubnub.s3.amazonaws.com/sencha-touch/index.html)

Code [here](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/app-showcase/sencha-touch)

To integrate PubNub, the minified javascript library is included in `/resources/js` and added to the project in `app.json` like this:

```
{
    "path": "resources/js/pubnub-3.1.min.js"
},
```

Then, in app.js, in launch(), add this:

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key   : 'demo',
    subscribe_key : 'demo',
    ssl           : false,
    origin        : 'pubsub.pubnub.com'
});
```

From there, you can use `pubnub.publish()` and `pubnub.subscribe()` like normal.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use websockets. It's easy to work with like SocketIO